# How to add value to hidden input field using ES6

Tags: javascript

I would like to take this jQuery statement and change it to be ES6. This currently looks for the item introducer and if it exists we add it to a hidden input field.

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("introducer") === null) {
  console.log('nope');
} else {
  console.log('exists');
  $("input[name=Origin]").val("Introducer");
}
```

I have tried the following but console errors on .value

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("introducer") === null) {
  console.log('nope');
} else {
  console.log('exists');
  document.getElementsByName("input[name=Origin]").value("Introducer");
}
```

Any suggestions or guidance would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `value` is a property not a function ... `getElementsByName` takes a name, not a selector - and returns a collection of elements, not a single element ... so, you'll want `document.querySelector("input[name=Origin]").value = "Introducer";` instead of the what you  wrote :p

Answer (score 0):

In ES6, to get an element the way you would in jQuery, instead of using `$()`, you can use `document.querySelector()`. TO set an input's value, rather than using the jQuery `val()` function, we can use the native JS value property which we set using `value =`:

```js
if (sessionStorage.getItem('introducer') === null) {
  console.log('nope');
} else {
  console.log('exists');
  document.querySelector('input[name=Origin]').value = 'Introducer';
}
```

If you don't need the console logs, you can shorten the if/else to just the else condition by switching the `===` to `!==`:

```js
if (sessionStorage.getItem('introducer') !== null) document.querySelector('input[name=Origin]').value = 'Introducer';
```